# Не работает onOptionsItemSelected при использовании toolBar

Tags: android

```
public class DKP extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dkp);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.dkp_tb);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.tb_textView: finish(); break;
        case R.id.tb_imageView: finish(); break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Данная строчка

`Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.dkp_tb);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Я как понимаю заменяет ActionBar ToolBarом, в таком случае должна работать функция onOptionsItemSelected, чтобы по этой функции получить доступ к элементам toolBara, но она не работает.

Только не говорите что нужно к каждому элементу получать доступ отдельно как к view...

Comment: onPrepareMenuOptions не забыли?

Comment: Не работал с ним

Comment: onOptionsItemSelected не будет работать, если вы не вызвали onPrepareMenuOptions

Comment: все равно не работает

Comment: @АндройдАндройд, можете создать ответ, а в нем написать код как нужно обрабатывать нажатия элементов в toolBar?

Comment: Я так понимаю, вам надо не к пунктам меню, описанным в `res/menu` обращаться, а к неким дочерним вьюхам-потомкам вашего кастомного Toolbar-а?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб,  да я работаю с Viewхами, не с меню. Если бы работал с menu, тогда зачем мне использовать Toolbar и лишний код писать. Я как понял Toolbar придумали чтобы в ActionBar можно было обычные вьюхи закидывать

Comment: Не, тулбар не для этого и так не работает. Придётся вам по старинке через findViewById работать. Как к меню элементам обратиться точно не получится.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ясно, буду знач через fdinView. А для чего ToolBar нужен тогда, если все тоже можно через ActionBar добиться

Comment: Toolbar можно использовать где угодно как обычную вьюху. В этом её преимущество.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Устанавливаем для обработки нажатий Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.dkp_tb);  
 toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
```

Обрабатываем нажатия в методе onMenuItemClick(MenuItem)

```
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.delete) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.save) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

И еще:

```
public class DKP extends AppCompatActivity  implements Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener
```

Answer (score 4):

Видимо не знает откуда брать id. Попробуйте добавить:

```
@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

В Toolbar вы работаете с меню точно также как и в ActionBar, Toolbar просто заменяет его. Если используете во фрагменте, то не забудьте еще добавить в методе onCreate `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`.